# reactjs - render route with component dynamically via json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, components, react-router-dom

I am new to react and generally in javascript.

Furthermore, I do have a json file which i want to get the url value  and render a component with that name.

```
{
  "MTs": {
    "MenuItems": {
      "Main": {
        "key": "1",
        "url": "about",
        "visible": true
      },
      "Add Status": {
        "key": "2",
        "url": "topics",
        "visible": true
      },
   }
}
```

My code:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState({ MTs: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(props.role + ".json")
      .then(function (response) {
        // console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (myJson) {
        // console.log(myJson);
        setData(myJson);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);


  var url = [];
  var val = function (data) {
    for (var key in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        for (var title in data[key].MenuItems) {
          if (data[key].MenuItems[title].visible == true) {
            url.push(
            <Route
              path={"/"+ data[key].MenuItems[title].url}
              component={data[key].MenuItems[title].url}
            />
            );
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return url;
  };
  return <div>{val(data)}</div>;
};
```

it doesnt render for the reason that its an array and adds double quotes "" in the Component name.

Is there any way or "better way" to do that ?

Expected result

```
<Route
  path="/about"
  component={about}
/>
<Route
  path="/topics"
  component={topics}
/>
<Route path="/datagrid" component={etc} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this add your components to a object like this

```js
const Component = {
  "about": <About />,
  "topics": <Topics />
}
```

and then call when loops

```js
<Route path={"/"+ data[key].MenuItems[title].url} component={Component[data[key].MenuItems[title].url]} />
```

Comment: Hi Sam, the issue is that i cant change the json file. i need somehow to automatically get that string from "url" and convert it to object i guess?

Comment: First you don't need to change the  json. You need to add all your dynamic components to a separate object like Component variable. When you loop you can use Component object to call the component based on URL that you are passing.

Comment: Hi Sam. I guess this is the way i should do it. but I am not experience enough (new to ReactJS) to add the components to a seperate object from json file and loop through them. Is there any suggestion on code?